# Make leaflet only display markers on start and endpoint whilst having multiple waypoints in route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

Currently I initiate my Leaflet map in Angular like this:

```js
private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [ 51.4381919, 5.4797248 ],
      zoom: 13
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      minZoom: 3,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });
    tiles.addTo(this.map);

    L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
        L.latLng(51.4508647, 5.4509124),
        L.latLng(51.443867, 5.45591),
        L.latLng(51.442804, 5.4648277)
      ],
    }).addTo(this.map);
  }
```

I have 3 waypoints, to calculate a route (this can go up to 1000's depending on how many datapoints I fetch from my database)
[image: Currently Leaflet displays 3 markers]

Currently Leaflet displays 3 markers, as I assigned it to do. But I want it to no matter the amount of waypoints I have, to draw a route but only display the first and last marker.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `createMarker` function in `Routing.plan`:

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
  plan: new L.Routing.Plan([
        L.latLng(51.4508647, 5.4509124),
        L.latLng(51.443867, 5.45591),
        L.latLng(51.442804, 5.4648277)
  ],{
    createMarker: function(i, waypoint, n){
        if(i === 0 || i === n - 1){
        // show markers
        return L.marker(waypoint.latLng);
      }
      return false;
    }
  })
}).addTo(mymap);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qhbjua2k/